# How can I run that Python script I downloaded from GitHub?

Tags: python, github, python-module, openmaptiles

https://github.com/AliFlux/MapTilesDownloader
I tried the following:

```
PS C:\Program Files\MapTilesDownloader-master\src> python server.py
```

but I received the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 3, in <module>
    from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
ImportError: No module named http.server
```

Could you please help me solve this problem?
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Are you using python 3? Looks like the script requires 3 but you have an older python version

Answer (score 0):

It should be because you have the wrong Python version, you need Python 3 to use http.server

Check out this [link](https://github.com/waveform80/pistreaming/issues/14), this person also has a similar issue, try starting the server with `python3 server.py`, you may have to download Python 3 if it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed the first part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that you are either not using python3 or that you do not have the [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) library installed. To install pillow you can do:

```
pip3 install pillow
```

(you could use pip instead of pip3)
in your terminal/command line and then do:

```
python3 server.py
```

If python3 does not work, it might mean that python3 is not installed, follow the instructions on the [python](https://www.python.org) website to do so.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem.